# suspend thread took more than allowed time

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I use MvvmCross and have a simple AppStart class:

```
public class AppStart: MvxNavigatingObject, IMvxAppStart
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The login service.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IUserDataService _userService;

    public AppStart(IUserDataService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async void Start(object hint = null)
    {
        // If your application uses a secure API this first call attempts to log the user into the application
        // using any credentials stored from a previous session.  If there are
        // none stored we should present the login screen, else go straight into the app
        if (await _userService.Login())
        {
            ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to debug the application, it crashed just after displaying splashscreen with the following error:

```
suspend_thread suspend took 201 ms, which is more than the allowed 200 ms
```

If I comment out the userService.Login() line it is ok

This error comes after I upgrade to Xamarin 4.2.2.11 but I don't know if it is linked to this update or not.
I use Xamarin.Android 7.0.2.42

I'm looking for a way to never suspend thread so basically I was expected that async Start method should work in MvvmCross but seems not the case or maybe I'm not doing the good things

Here is the logcat logs:

```
    Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging[0x7f73a477de00] -> mscorlib[0x7f73a477c700]: 26
Tablet_API_21   Error   6091        suspend_thread suspend took 201 ms, which is more than the allowed 200 ms
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    gralloc_ranchu  Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Platform[0x7f73abc78580] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0x7f7394645680]: 3
Tablet_API_21   Warning 2180    IInputConnectionWrapper showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    OpenGLRenderer  Enabling debug mode 0
Tablet_API_21   Info    6091    OpenGLRenderer  Initialized EGL, version 1.4
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    OpenGLRenderer  Render dirty regions requested: true
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref VoxStarterXamarin.Droid[0x7f73a477d100] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4[0x7f7394618a00]: 4
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref VoxStarterXamarin.Droid[0x7f73a477d100] -> Square.AndroidTimesSquare[0x7f7394618680]: 2
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f73a477d380] -> Mono.Android[0x7f7394646a80]: 16
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f73a477d380] -> mscorlib[0x7f73a477c700]: 28
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Shared[0x7f73a477db00] -> Mono.Android[0x7f7394646a80]: 15
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Shared[0x7f73a477db00] -> mscorlib[0x7f73a477c700]: 27
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging[0x7f73a477de00] -> Mono.Android[0x7f7394646a80]: 14
Tablet_API_21   Info    1490    ActivityManager Displayed VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid/md5d102fb223d7168b41e10cb7cf854dfb3.SplashScreen: +9s623ms
Tablet_API_21   Error   1490    InputDispatcher channel '302f064b VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid/md5d102fb223d7168b41e10cb7cf854dfb3.SplashScreen (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
Tablet_API_21   Warning 1490    InputDispatcher channel '302f064b VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid/md5d102fb223d7168b41e10cb7cf854dfb3.SplashScreen (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
Tablet_API_21   Warning 1490    ActivityManager Force removing ActivityRecord{1b02a099 u0 VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid/md5d102fb223d7168b41e10cb7cf854dfb3.SplashScreen t19}: app died, no saved state
Tablet_API_21   Info    1490    ActivityManager Process VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid (pid 6091) has died
Tablet_API_21   Info    1141    Zygote  Process 6091 exited due to signal (6)
Tablet_API_21   Error   1490    InputDispatcher channel '302f064b VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid/md5d102fb223d7168b41e10cb7cf854dfb3.SplashScreen (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
Tablet_API_21   Warning 1490    InputDispatcher channel '302f064b VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid/md5d102fb223d7168b41e10cb7cf854dfb3.SplashScreen (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
Tablet_API_21   Info    1490    ActivityManager Displayed VoxStarterXamarin.Droid.VoxStarterXamarin.Droid/md5d102fb223d7168b41e10cb7cf854dfb3.SplashScreen: +9s623ms
Tablet_API_21   Error   6091        suspend_thread suspend took 201 ms, which is more than the allowed 200 ms
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    gralloc_ranchu  Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Platform[0x7f73abc78580] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0x7f7394645680]: 3
Tablet_API_21   Warning 2180    IInputConnectionWrapper showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    OpenGLRenderer  Enabling debug mode 0
Tablet_API_21   Info    6091    OpenGLRenderer  Initialized EGL, version 1.4
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    OpenGLRenderer  Render dirty regions requested: true
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref VoxStarterXamarin.Droid[0x7f73a477d100] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4[0x7f7394618a00]: 4
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref VoxStarterXamarin.Droid[0x7f73a477d100] -> Square.AndroidTimesSquare[0x7f7394618680]: 2
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f73a477d380] -> Mono.Android[0x7f7394646a80]: 16
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f73a477d380] -> mscorlib[0x7f73a477c700]: 28
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Shared[0x7f73a477db00] -> Mono.Android[0x7f7394646a80]: 15
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Shared[0x7f73a477db00] -> mscorlib[0x7f73a477c700]: 27
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging[0x7f73a477de00] -> Mono.Android[0x7f7394646a80]: 14
Tablet_API_21   Debug   6091    Mono    Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging[0x7f73a477de00] -> mscorlib[0x7f73a477c700]: 26
```

One important note is that is working if I build and deploy even in Debug mode, the error occured only when I enter in debug mode (F5 from Visual studio 2015)

Comment: Be very careful with `async void` here. It doesn't seem to be an event handler and thus is a fire and forget method. You should at the minimum return `Task`. Another question would be, what are the contents of `_userService.Login()`? Finally, please ensure you try the latest bits of MvvmCross and Xamarin(There is a Beta build which might address this with a new Mono)

Comment: The Login method is simply a method to get token value from a setting base (using Setting plugin from MvvmCross).

Answer (score 1):

Each OS has a time limit for how long your App can take to get to its first screen. iOS is particularly strict about this. MvvmCross enforces this in their start up process as well.

Basically, your `await _userService.Login()` takes too long.

You should consider moving this to a different place. My advice would be to create a different page for a Splash Screen, show that immediately, then start your login process after the Splsh Page is opened. Once your login check is done, push the new page over the Splash, and remove the Splash page from your history.

Comment: Actually I use the MvxSplashscreen I was expecting that MvvmCross could handle this kind of thing. So your advice is to ShowViewModel a view that contains the same splashscreen, do the login process inside of this ViewModel and then load either the loginView or the mainView. Right?

Comment: That's correct! MvxSplashscreen is still not technically part of the app start process. Basically, `IMvxAppStart.Start` has a time limit. So everything you run in there has to be done in 200ms. Longer processes should be kicked off from somewhere else.

Comment: As @SuavePirate points out. In `AppStart` you haven't set the `Root` `ViewController` yet, this is done by either of your `ShowViewModel` calls. Taking too long here will yield the error you are seeing. MvvmCross doesn't enforce any time limit here. The OS is very strict about it though.